# when ever i rum my appilication i get this error

Tags: android

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'D:\Workspace\18.05.2017\cloudfy_B2B\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-run_9af49a37f5fd0a1122f7dcfc33359c6e87d300f5\classes.dex'.'

Answer (score -1):

Disable your antivirus software while running project in android studio.